# 2nd Order Regular Triangular Mesh on Rectangular domain

Tags: list-manipulation, finite-element-method, mesh

I want to create a mesh of 6 noded triangular elements  ( 2 nd order element) on a rectangular domain as shown. (0,0) can be seen at left bottom corner with the whole mesh in the positive quadrant.

[image: 500 Element Regular 6 noded Triangular Mesh on 254 by 101.6 Sq.mm]

I tried the following

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
m2 = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {254, 101.6}], 
   "MeshElementType" -> TriangleElement, 
   MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 2000/4}, "MeshOrder" -> 2];
Show[m2["Wireframe"], 
 m2["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]]]
```

The output is
[image: Random 2nd order triangular mesh]

My problem is

1. I want a regular mesh as shown in the top figure (not a random one as seen in the bottom figure).
2. I want to display all the interior node numbers & element numbers in the mesh. In the bottom figure, only the boundary nodes are numbered.
3. I am looking for control over the number of elements on the x & y axes.

Please help.

Comment: Does anyone know where I can get the answer?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What exactly is the problem? There are similar examples in the documentation.

Comment: @user21 I edited the question. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the documentation: Start with ToElementMesh#188109273 (paste this into the help system), then use a rule like `{i1_Integer,i2_,i3_,i4}->{{i1,i2,i3},{i3,i4,i1}}` to convert the incidents to triangles. You can use `MeshOrderAlteration` to get a second order mesh. You can display the element numbers in each element, but for all node numbers you have to write something like `i=1;Graphics[Text[i++,#]&/@mesh["Coordinates"]]`